# Align DataGrid Column Header to Center

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to align `WPF DataGrid Column Header` text to **Center**. I created a style and attached that using the `HeaderStyle` property as below.

**Style**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CenterGridHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Column**

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
   Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" 
   HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"/>
```

But this does not align Column Header text to the Center. How can I do this?

Comment: You can find the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943729/how-to-set-style-for-datagrid-header-in-wpf

Comment: Try like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943729/how-to-set-style-for-datagrid-header-in-wpf

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Check this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre"
                          Binding="{Binding Nombre}">
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                 Value="Center" />
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Would be appreciated any comment why Your solution does work and not solution of @Bishan.

Comment: I think we can be happy that at WPF is not everything of the type object() and we need to add every single property via styles and bindings. What a laborious f....

Answer (score 22):

It should be StaticResource instead of DynamicResource in the Column:

**Style**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CenterGridHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Column**

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
   Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" 
   HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}"/>
```

Comment: IMO this is the actual correct answer. The accepted answer provides an alternative but does not actually say why the code provided in the question is wrong.

Comment: Using this `DataGridColumnHeader` style implicitly (i.e. without x:Key) also allows to set all column headers to be centered, regardless of their type (Text, CheckBox, ComboBox, Column Template).

Answer (score 2):

There is a response for doing it programmatically at AutoGeneratingColumn:

```
 private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
                e.Column.HeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
                e.Column.HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));

    }
```

Tip, use attributes:

```
public class ColumnNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public HorizontalAlignment Alignment { get; set;}
    public ColumnNameAttribute(HorizontalAlignment alignment){
        Alignment = alignment;
}

public class Example(){
    [ColumnName(HorizontalAlignment.Center)]
    public string Column {get; set;}
}

 private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
   var desc = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyDescriptor;
   var att = desc.Attributes[typeof(ColumnNameAttribute)] as ColumnNameAttribute;
   if(att != null){
           e.Column.HeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
           e.Column.HeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, att.Alignment));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
  <Style>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed here while searching for the same problem for *Row Headers* alignment. In case anyone else was searching, the solution is as simple as:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
    <Style.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: The question is about changing a single column.

Comment: @ChrisBordeman: Styles can be keyed to apply them to a specific scope.

Comment: Of course, but then you should show that instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using to change the header text alignment.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" MinWidth="60" Header=" ID " IsReadOnly="True">                                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#c0c0c0"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
     </Style>                                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>                                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" TextAlignment="Center" />
     </DataTemplate>                                                       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```