# Center column header in datagrid in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to center the Column header in DataGrid. To add DataGrid in UWP UI i'm using 
nuget package "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid" as mentioned in microsoft documentation link [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics) . I tried searching here but there is solution for WPF only it's in this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131091/align-datagrid-column-header-to-center).

In this code i can't use TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader".

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
 <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Area Name" Binding="{Binding Height_m}" Width="*">
  <controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
   </Style>
  </controls:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
 </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

It Shows
Exception : The name "DataGridColumnHeader" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridColumnHeader` is not under the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls` namespace, but under the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives` namespace.

So you need to add the corresponding namespace reference:

```xml
xmlns:prim="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives"

...

<controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="prim:DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200" />
    </Style>
</controls:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

The `MinWidth` is set to better view the centering effect, if you don't need it, you can delete it.

However, because the width of the column is affected by the content of the column, you may observe that the header is not centered, then you can consider setting a `MinWidth`.

Thanks